# How to read only one expression at a time in Guile Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, guile

I am trying to make a reader extension in Guile Scheme. When writing this reader extension, I would like to use a guile function that reads in only one expression at a time, like `read-expression` and `read-sexp`, but these functions do not appear to be available in the default namespace. I am unable to find documentation on these functions, so I do not know what modules to import to use them. I know they are implemented in the Guile source code (in read.c), as `scm_read_expression` and `scm_read_sexp` respectively. I had been assuming that these functions are exposed to some Scheme API, hence the "`scm_`" prefix... Is that assumption valid? Either way, are there functions available in some Guile module that would allow me to read in only a single expression at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When asking this question, I mistakenly believed that `read` would read all the expressions in the given port. In fact, `read` only reads in one expression, and so has the behavior needed for my purposes. See the manual entry here: https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Scheme-Read.html